# Java Script banner with flexible timer based on hours

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I want to make a short script to show a banner in specific period of time. like this:
From 9:30 AM. to 10 AM. show banner 1
From 11 AM. to 12:15 AM. show banner 2
From 8:10 PM. to 10 PM. show banner 3
ans so on.

I make this up but it doesn't work in a right way.

Please help me to understand and fix the problem.
how can I add minutes ? It seems it just work with hours.

Special Thanks

````
<head>

<script>
var current= new Date()
var day_night=current.getHours()
if (day_night<=2){
    document.write("<img src='1.png' style='width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto;'>");
}
else if (day_night<=3){
    document.write("<img src='3.jpg' style='width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto;'>");
}
else if (day_night<=4){
    document.write("<img src='4.png' style='width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto;'>");
}
else{
    document.write("<img src='night.gif' style='width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto;'>");
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
</body> ```
````

Comment: Just look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. and instead of trying to do it with images, try something simple first, like outputting the day_night value on the screen instead of images. Create the smallest usable piece

Answer (score 0):

You can try smth like this

```
const timetable = [
        { banner: '<img src="night.gif" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto;">', fromTime: '10:00', toTime: '11:30' },
        { banner: '<img src="1.gif" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto;">', fromTime: '12:00', toTime: '12:15' },
    ];


    function getCurrentBanner() {
        const date = new Date();
        const hour = date.getHours();
        const minutes = date.getMinutes();

        let currentBanner = null;
        timetable.forEach(item => {
            const [fromHour, fromMinutes] = item.fromTime.split(':');
            const [toHour, toMinutes] = item.toTime.split(':');
            if (hour >= Number(fromHour) && minutes >= Number(fromMinutes) && hour <= Number(toHour) && minutes <= Number(toMinutes)) {
                currentBanner = item.banner;
                return;
            }
        })
        return currentBanner;
    }
    const b = getCurrentBanner();
```

Comment: I  used as a </script> but it doesn't work. but thanks anyway man.

Comment: then you better use it before body tag is closed.

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
...
</script>
</body>
</html>